# How to display three widgets inline horizontally in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new in Wordpress in development.

I made one sidebar on my front page

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(

    'name'=> 'Homepage sidebar center',
    'id' => 'sidebar-center',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="center-links">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
     'before_title' => '<h2 class="center-links-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
```

and I want to display three widgets inline, I have some Image widget witch display images. I try to make

and to write in css display: inline but it doesn't work.

Any sugestion? Please!!!

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="inner-content-links">
            <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Homepage sidebar center') ) : ?>   
                    <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS you tried?

Comment: I tried few things. For example: #sidebar-center { display: inline; } and inline-block; also tried to put <ul> and <li> tags after <div id="inner-content-links"> but doesn't work for me.